# Save and load Guava Optional<?>s in MongoDB using Spring-Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How to tune the mapping of the Guava `Optional`s (or later the JDK8 Optionals) with Spring-Data-MongoDb?

As an example the following class should be mapped like the json below.

```
@Data
public class Test
{
    Optional<String> stringOptionalNull    = null;
    Optional<String> stringOptionalAbsent  = Optional.absent();
    Optional<String> stringOptionalPresent = Optional.of("ExampleValue");   
}
```

Json (Note: The Null and absent cases are treated in the same manner):

```
{
   "stringOptionalPresent" : "ExampleValue"
}
```

When they are converted back to java again, the `null` and `absent` should be translated to `Optional.absent()`.

From the [Spring Data MongoDB Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.custom-converters) I read that the `org.springframework...Converter`s are the way to go. But with the API I was not able to treat the `null` cases correct.

The is a complete testcase to reproduce the problem. It hands in a `null` and tests that the loaded object contains only `Optional.absent()`.

```
public class OptionalMongoDbTest
{
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class ClassWithOptionals
    {
        private final Optional<String> stringOptionalNull;
        private final Optional<String> stringOptionalPresent;
        private final Optional<String> stringOptionalAbsent;
    }

    public static class OptionalToStringConverter<T> implements Converter<Optional<T>, String>
    {
        @Override
        public String convert(final Optional<T> arg0)
        {
            return arg0.isPresent() ? arg0.get().toString() : null;
        }
    }

    public static class StringToOptionalConverter implements Converter<String, Optional<String>>
    {
        @Override
        public Optional<String> convert(final String arg0)
        {
            return Optional.fromNullable(arg0);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void persisted_object_should_be_equal() throws Exception
    {
        // Setup Mongodb connection
        final SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "test");
        final MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(mongoDbFactory, new MongoMappingContext());

        // Register Custom Converter
        converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new OptionalToStringConverter(), new StringToOptionalConverter())));
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();

        final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);

        // Test the mapping
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection(ClassWithOptionals.class);

        final ClassWithOptionals objectToSave = new ClassWithOptionals(null, Optional.of("ExampleValue"), Optional.<String> absent());
        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave);

        final ClassWithOptionals objectFromMongo = mongoTemplate.findAll(ClassWithOptionals.class).get(0);

        // TODO: That test fails because there are null values comming from the databases
        assertThat(objectFromMongo, is(new ClassWithOptionals(Optional.<String> absent(), Optional.of("ExampleValue"), Optional.<String> absent())));
    }
}
```

Furthermore the json generated by this test looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5343d8a5e4b0215d78a322d0"),
    "stringOptionalPresent" : "ExampleValue",
    "stringOptionalAbsent" : null // this line should be removed.
}
```

**Edit**

I think that is not possible because spring data mongo doesn't trigger custom conversions on null objects.
That is because of this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java#L1037-L1041

Comment: The _very goal_ of `Optional` is to avoid nulls! Why give the possibility to have a null `Optional` at all?

Comment: I know, but anyway we need to convert it correctly!?

Comment: So, basically, what you want to know is how to serialize an `Optional` using MongoDB's API?

Comment: Yes, serialize and deserialize. The best for me would be an conversion that is compatible with spring data.

Comment: And how would you deserialized to an `Optional.absent()`? I'm not saying that it is not doable, but you'll have to explicit what you want. Also, another option would be to have the getter only return an `Optional`; the setter would work "normally".

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spring so I don't know whether this will work for you but try and make your setter work "normally" and transform your getter to this:

```
public Optional<String> getFoo()
{
    return Optional.fromNullable(foo);
}
```

If `foo` is `null`, it will be an `Optional.absent()` for which `.isPresent()` will return `false`.

In Java 8 (which has "stolen" `Optional` from Guava) the API is a little different; it is not `Optional.absent()` but `Optional.empty()`, and `.fromNullable()` has become `.ofNullable()`.

Comment: Hi, that will not solve the conversion Problem. I get this exception because optional (of course) has no default constructor. org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException In the question I asked for help in the mapping

Comment: Then make it so that Spring ignores the instance variables and use the setters instead... Don't know how to do that with Spring though